# How do I mount the .img files under Ubuntu?

Tags: mount, ubuntu, filesystem

I just downloaded the Debian and Arch Linux files and I would like to mount before I burn into the SD card. How can I mount the img?

I tried to mount but I'm getting the following error:

```
sudo mount -o loop archlinuxarm-13-06-2012.img /mnt/
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

Is that yaffs2? How can I mount the yaffs2, as far as I know it's not supported yet under Ubuntu 12.04, and I couldn't  find any package.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The Hard Way

Read my other answer on [Is it possible to update, upgrade and install software before flashing an image?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/855/86).

You need to calculate the offset of the filesystem you wish to mount.

## The Easy, yet experimental way

Consider using my new utility [piimg](https://github.com/alexchamberlain/piimg). Just build and run

```
$ sudo ./piimg mount archlinuxarm-13-06-2012.img /mnt
```

> **NOTE** This hasn't been fully tested yet.

### What does `piimg` do?

`piimg` performs a series of mounts by analysing the image and setting up the correct loop devices and mounts. It mounts `/` first, then `/boot`, binds`/dev` (recursively), binds `/sys` and creates `/proc`. You need to do the opposite to unmount, but there should be a `umount` subcommand soon.

> **DISCLAIMER** I, Alex Chamberlain, am the lead developer of `piimg`. As such,
>   I may be biased towards the use of `piimg` in relation to other methods.

Comment: @iungi Which method did you use?

Comment: Thank you for this valuable work.
I just pointed out that it is necessary to install the package libparted0-dev to build correctly.
I will use your utility and I'll point out potential problems.
Just a little note: it seems more logical to install in /usr/local/sbin a program reserved for root !
Best regards.

Comment: <br/>
Another note, there is an oversight in your command line:<br/>
$ sudo ./piimg **mount** sd.img /mnt

Comment: @MarkBooth I haven't worked on `piimg` for a long time. I guess that the docs for that need updating, rather than this answer (given it doesn't tell you how to build it!)

Comment: @MarkBooth Oh there were 2. Yes, it needs updating. *Done*

Comment: Thanks Alex, I only noticed that after I'd commented too. I've already flagged both of *epsilonrt*s answers.

Comment: See how to compile instructions: [https://github.com/alexchamberlain/piimg/issues/2#issuecomment-382514016](https://github.com/alexchamberlain/piimg/issues/2#issuecomment-382514016)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the image is a complete disk image including a partition table, not an image of an individual partition.

Theres a couple of ways round this, one way is to calculate an offset and use that for mounting (see alex's answer for more details).

Another way if you have a recent kernel and a recent version of losetup is to use the -P option to losetup e.g.

losetup -P -f <filename>

this will create a series of device nodes. The main /dev/loop<number> node and also nodes for each partition at /dev/loop<number>p<number> . You can then work with the device like any other paritioned device.

When you have finished you can remove the loopback device with

losetup -d /dev/loop<number>

Answer (score 0):

The super easy way: `gnome-disks`

Then click the 'hamburger' next to 'Disks' and choose the option 'Attach Disk Image (.Iso, .Img)'.

I used it without problems to mount a Dietpi Raspberry Pi image with WinDiskImager.