# Making a new image after changing a few parameter of Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, boot, image

I got Raspbian on a SD card.  It is working.  Then I installed a few program, modified some visual settings, and added some config files.

What I would like to do now is release this image to other people and have it really easy to deploy.  What are a few of the steps needed to go from working SD card to getting a `.img` file?

Also, if possible, is there a way to "embed" a UID, like a MAC address, in the image so that the end user does not have to configure it?  This might be a more tricky question but if you had a pointer on the first step it would be helpful.

Comment: See [this question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/311/40). Just make sure your configuration is generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from your question I assume you use one of the installers to get the Raspbian image on your SD card.

You can also use [dd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) for this. dd works in both ways, so that means you can use it to create an image yourself as well.

Try the following on a system with dd to make an image of your SD card:

```
dd if=/dev/sdX of=/path/to/image.img bs=1M
```

In the above example, /dev/sdX must point to the SD card. If you don't know what this is, you can find out by using:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

which will show you all connected media and their partitions. More information on fdisk can be found [here](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fdisk).
Another option is to look at the last bit of dmesg, just after plugging your SD card(reader) in:

```
dmesg | tail
```

All the above commands are very common on unix systems. If you don't use one, you can try a linux livecd. There are hundreds if not thousands of those available.

Comment: Any idea how the img can be modified before it is copied?  So, what I would like to do is modify a file in the image to contain the MAC address and UID for a given RaspPi.

Answer (score 2):

## Creating image

*All* you need to do is `dd`, as explained in [How do I backup my Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/311/86).

However, this will capture all personal files, configuration etc.

#### Off-topic

I'd be interested in adding these features to [piimg](https://github.com/alexchamberlain/piimg), perhaps raise an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/alexchamberlain/piimg)?

Comment: This looks great.  It is a little overkill for what I need at the moment.   It would be really great if I could add certain parameters to the image using the utility. Like for example a MAC address so that it can be really easy for a person to config the SD card, plug it into their RaspPi, then go.

Comment: The MAC address is (should?) be part of the Ethernet chip, and isn't (as far as I'm aware) configurable. Do you mean IP address?

Comment: I gave the MAC address as a bad example.  Ideally, I want to get a unique ID onto the device so that the user doesn't have to enter it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could use the serial number of the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: that is a great idea!  Like [this](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/09/getting-your-raspberry-pi-serial-number-using-python/)?

Comment: Yeah, how do you need it? Python? Bash?

Comment: bash, because I want to put this in a startup file.

Comment: Actually, I'm thinking about it a little more. I want to link an instance of the software to the main server.  I think it is going to be easier to do this all in software.  Becuase otherwise, I need to have the person enter in the serial of their device.  It is easier if I can give them a preconfiged SD card and have them plug it in.

Comment: @AlexisK See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/2086/86

Comment: It seems like you know a ton about this so I thought this might be a good place to ask.  Is there a way to add a .config file to the root directory of the .iso that other programs can read out of?  So the use case would be to have the user put in two value, then have a python script create a custom .iso file with the values in it.  What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: I assume you mean img files, which are subtly different to iso files (I think). What do you want to configure? Would this script run on Linux?

Comment: Yes, it would be on linux.  I would want on the .img file is a persons name to greet them.  My understanding that .iso and .img files were the same.  But that was just based on reading.  I don't have first ahnd experience with it.

Comment: You want to edit `/etc/motd.tail`. See http://wiki.debian.org/motd and http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/855/86.