# How do I get the serial number?

Tags: setup

Where can I find the serial number of the Raspberry Pi I am currently using?

Comment: is the serial number printed on the device or is it only available through software?  I see there is a sticker on the device but I don't think that it is related to the serial number.  It would be nice to know the ID of the device without having to power it on and connect it.

Comment: @AlexisK It's only available in software.

Comment: Correct, there doesn't seem to be any relation with the sticker and serial number.  I've read the sticker of a number of Pi's and tried to decode it.  While Raspberry probably has internal lists connecting both, it doesn't seem that there is any way to calculate the serial or MAC from it.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The serial number can be found in `/proc/cpuinfo`; for example,

```
 pi@raspberrypi:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
 Processor       : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
 BogoMIPS        : 697.95
 Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls
 CPU implementer : 0x41
 CPU architecture: 7
 CPU variant     : 0x0
 CPU part        : 0xb76
 CPU revision    : 7

 Hardware        : BCM2708
 Revision        : 1000002
 Serial          : 000000000000000d
```

## Bash

You can use very basic bash piping

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Serial | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Since tabs are used on the left side of the colon, cutting on the space character will reliably catch only the serial number.

> Prior versions of this answer cut on the colon, which produced a leading space in the variable. That leading space is not removed during variable assignment as was previously suggested.

## Bash/Perl

In Bash, it is very simple to extract... by using Perl. Use

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | perl -n -e '/^Serial\s*:\s([0-9a-f]{16})$/ && print "$1\n"'
```

For example,

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | perl -n -e '/^Serial\s*:\s([0-9a-f]{16})$/ && print "$1\n"'
000000000000000d
```

## Python

[Raspberry Spy](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/09/getting-your-raspberry-pi-serial-number-using-python/) provides a very useful Python example.

```
def getserial():
  # Extract serial from cpuinfo file
  cpuserial = "0000000000000000"
  try:
    f = open('/proc/cpuinfo','r')
    for line in f:
      if line[0:6]=='Serial':
        cpuserial = line[10:26]
    f.close()
  except:
    cpuserial = "ERROR000000000"

  return cpuserial
```

#### References

1. [Licence key product pages](http://www.raspberrypi.com/mpeg-2-license-key/)
2. [Raspberry Spy: Getting Your Raspberry Pi Serial Number Using Python](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/09/getting-your-raspberry-pi-serial-number-using-python/)

Comment: Perl will accept filenames as arguments. It's not necessary to use `cat`.

Comment: the last 6 digits of my serial number are the same as the last 6 digits of my MAC address.  Is this true for you?

Comment: @AlexisK: It's true for me.

Comment: < redirection also works, so it's a useless use of cat.

Comment: @XTL I prefer to use pipes than input redirection; it flows nicely. Just personal preference.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Just personal preference using cat.

Comment: MAC is indeed linked to the serial.  The first 6 characters of the MAC (B8:27:EB) are assigned by the  [IEEE Standards Association](https://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/public.html) to the "Raspberry Pi Foundation".   However there's no hardware relation with both, only the CPU one is baked in.

Comment: Is there any way to get this information physically? I mean on the board, so I dont have to boot every pi to get this information.

Comment: Is it unique? seems a little short ... in my serial only 4 bytes used, all rest are zeroes

Comment: Why not just `grep -i Serial /proc/cpuinfo | cut -d ' ' -f 2` ?

Comment: @rynop The idea is that every utility has a specific purpose. Using `cat` is not useless, it makes it more readable and improves consistency. And for anyone taking the performance-argument, then you're wrong to use Bash in the first place.

Comment: It's a bad habit to get into. People tend to use `cat foo | bar` and then get confused when `bar` hits an error and doesn't print the file name. Or `bar` might do something unwanted when presented with an empty input when the real error was a permission or file system problem (bad SD cards anybody?) that should have been caught earlier.

Comment: `sed -ne 's/^Serial\s*:\s*//p' </proc/cpuinfo`, anybody?

Answer (score 30):

`/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/serial-number` [seems to be](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=250285) more universal nowadays.
And it doesn't require any additional processing.

```
# SN=$(cat /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/serial-number)
# echo $SN
0000000061c8eda7
```

BTW, here is model as well (`/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/model`)

Comment: This is a really good way that also avoids using pipes and stuff to get the serial number. Tested to work on my Rpi4. Will report if it doesn't work on previous models.

Comment: @gromain
Tested with 2b/3b/3b+ as well. It should work with any RPi with a DT-enabled kernel.

Answer (score 13):

## Bash/Grep

Using `grep`:

```
grep -Po '^Serial\s*:\s*\K[[:xdigit:]]{16}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

## Bash

Using pure Bash without using any external utilities:

```
pattern='^Serial.*([[:xdigit:]]{16})$'
while read -r line
do
    if [[ $line =~ $pattern ]]
    then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
done < /proc/cpuinfo
```

The output of either of the above is the same.

Comment: this is the only one that worked for me

Comment: This doesn't work: 'P' is an invalid option. At least in pcpAudioCore

Comment: @theking2: I'm afraid I'm unfamiliar with pcpAudioCore. The `-P` (Perl regex) is an option of modern versions of GNU `grep`.

Answer (score 9):

## Bash/Awk

Since this turned out to be some kind of "how many ways can you get the serial" here is the awk version

```
  awk '/^Serial\s*:\s/{print $3}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

Answer (score 8):

## NodeJS

For anyone interested here is a way to get the Raspberry Serial Number using NodeJS:

```
function getserial(){

   var fs = require('fs');

   var content = fs.readFileSync('/proc/cpuinfo', 'utf8');

   var cont_array = content.split("\n");

   var serial_line = cont_array[cont_array.length-2];

   var serial = serial_line.split(":");

   return serial[1].slice(1);

}
```

Comment: For whatever reason, content_array.length-2 doesn't always work for me. Sometimes it gives me "Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1" which is the "Model" line right after the "Serial" line. So I changed your function to this (see next comment) to make sure.

Comment: function getserial() {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var content = fs.readFileSync('/proc/cpuinfo', 'utf8');
    var cont_array = content.split("\n");
    var x = 0;
    var serial_line = "";
    while (x < cont_array.length) {
        serial_line = cont_array[x];
        if (serial_line.startsWith("Serial")) {
            return serial_line.split(":")[1].slice(1);
        }
        x++;
    }
}

Comment: @fivedogit's edit is a much more appropriate way to parse the output IMO. If you were telling a human how to parse that output, you'd tell them to look for the line beginning with 'Serial', not to look for the second line.

Answer (score 7):

```
grep -i serial /proc/cpuinfo | cut -d : -f2
```

Comment: programming golf is not encouraged on the web-site, because it's very difficult to follow your answer for beginners, especially if you don't write any explanation or detailed comment.

Comment: I'd oppose to call this answer "programming golf" comparing to even more cryptic one like "Bash/Awk". Actually, I intended to uplift this answer for sake of equality, but after running it on my PI and comparing to other version, won't do it because must admit, this answer is not giving precise output by inserting extra leading space. PS: I won't minus it too though

Comment: It still depends on the 'Serial' line being the second to last in the output. There's no guarantee this will always be the case and may change in future kernels. Far better to search for the 'Serial' header, as per @fivedogit's comment to another answer.

Answer (score 6):

Using `awk`:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Serial | awk ' {print $3}'
```

Comment: That's a nice example of [UUOC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat). Could be simply written `awk '/Serial/{print $3}' /proc/cpuinfo`

Answer (score 3):

The shortest and simplest hasn't been provided as an answer yet. This, in sed:

```
sed -n '/^Serial/{s/.* //;p}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

meaning:

- `sed -n` — run the stream editor without printing every line
- `/^Serial/` — match only lines that *start* with the word “Serial”
- `s/.* //;` — replace everything up until the last space with nothing (sed regexes are [greedy](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html#index-Greedy-regular-expression-matching-85), btw)
- `p` — print the result.

sed sometimes gets a bad name for being hard to use and cryptic, but it is available and works the same way (as long as you stick to POSIX conventions) on many types of Linux and Unix.

Comment: My one-liner to even remove leading zeros: `sed -n 's/^Serial\s*: 0*//p' /proc/cpuinfo`

Answer (score 3):

[Most-answered question on this SE?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Much_Ado_About_Nothing)... maybe just do this:

```
$ grep Serial /proc/cpuinfo
```

And as a bonus:

- Raspberry Pis have "randomly assigned" serial numbers that are written to non-volatile memory. [Long discussion here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=8985) on whether or not these serial numbers are unique, but the bottom line is that the algorithm is proprietary to the chip manufacturer. Which effectively means, "nobody knows if the serial number can be counted on to be truly unique". It's apparently considered ["unique enough" to protect a £2.40 MPEG-2 license key](http://www.raspberrypi.com/mpeg-2-license-key/) though - if that lets you sleep better :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Indeed this the way to get it.

It is funny that my Pi0 has the same data (serial) as above example. There is no diferentiator between my PI0 serial and the one posted by Alex Chamberlain

For PI3 yo got 4 procesors

```
#cat /proc/cpuinfo

processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt                                                                                                                      vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor       : 1
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt                                                                                                                      vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor       : 2
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt                                                                                                                      vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor       : 3
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt                                                                                                                      vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

Hardware        : BCM2709
Revision        : a02082
Serial          : 000000003d1d1c36
```

Answer (score 1):

I had posted my own answer elsewhere but tried one of the Answers on this recently edit Question.

I had previously said this could be found using `vcgencmd otp_dump | grep 28:` as the serial number is programmed into the [OTP register](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#otp-registers)
NOTE The value in OTP register 28 should be the definitive answer as all other methods are just an alternate method of accessing the value  programmed at manufacture.

These are 32 bit values represented in hex.

This DOES NOT agree with the value in `/proc/cpuinfo` in my Pi4 as shown by e.g. `awk '/Serial/ {print $3}' /proc/cpuinfo`

I had some time ago predicted the Foundation would run out of 32 bit numbers, which seems to have happened as it is now a 64 bit number with a leading `1`