# What information is on the label on the back of the RaspberryPi?

Tags: pi-3

There's a small label on the back of the RaspberryPi (this is a Pi3, but there's a similar one on the Pi2) that includes a 2D barcode. What's the information on this label?

[image]

For clarity, this one says:

```
400774
1401
703062
1618
```

In particular, I notice the 3rd line is the distinct across a few different Pi3's that I checked, while the rest are the same.

---

To answer a couple questions:

- The barcode decodes to the same as the text: `400774 1401 703062 1618`
- The MAC address of this Pi is: `b8:27:eb:d3:a3:6d`. Decimal conversions:

  - `d3` == 211, `a3` == 163, `6d` == 109
  - `d3a36d` == 13,869,933

Comment: (My guess, btw, is:  Product code / Revision / Serial number / Manufacture date)

Comment: I doubt the third one is a serial number or they would have wrapped around pretty quickly.  Also, I think the manufacture date is stenciled onto the board above that (in this case, "15 16").

Comment: As your real question seems to be identifying a specific Pi have a look at this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/how-do-i-get-the-serial-number, you may be able to get y with only a hostname. Expanding your question to explain why you want the info would help.

Comment: Indeed, I was hoping to be able to match physical and software identity, but as per that discussion it doesn't seem like that's possible. I'll take that bit out of the question, but I think it's still useful to have something explaining this sticker as there seems to be no documentation on it. If one of these is in fact a unique identifier, I could maintain my own mapping of it to MAC/serial. Without even knowing what it is, I don't know if there's anything useful that can be done.

Comment: Did you try one a [QR code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) scanner on it? (I haven't -- all apologies if it's just the Foundation website.)

Comment: The ethernet MAC of all Raspi start with b8:27:eb, the following triplets are made from the serial number. Check if they match.

Comment: @goldilocks Nope, same as the printed text.

Comment: @Janka I don't see any variation of MAC that matches the number.

Answer (score 2):

We seem to have an official explanation of what it is, but not precisely what information is on the sticker.  [According to James H](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=196673), one of the engineers,

> It's a Sony tracking sticker for quality control so they can track when/where it was made etc, in case there are issues.

After being asked about different styles of stickers, he elaborated:

> Different factories use different stickers I believe. When I asked the guy who knows about this I showed him one of my boards as an example, which was made in the Sony factory.

Further up in the thread, people speculated that the final 4-digit number is the YYWW manufacture date, which James neither confirmed nor denied.  I think it's a pretty safe guess though.