# Pass serial number when running chromium through command line

Tags: raspbian, boot, chromium

I'm looking for a way to pass in the Raspberry Pi serial number to Chromium when running from the command line.

`chromium-browser --incognito --noerrdialogs http://url.com?sn={serial}`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**2020-02-07 answer:**
You can get the serial number with:

```
rpi ~$ cat /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/serial-number
10000000cd0297b1
```

So the command to call chromium on the command line with serial number resulted in:

```
rpi ~$ chromium-browser --incognito --noerrdialogs http://url.com?sn=$(cat /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/serial-number)
```

Comment: 4 years later and I haven't thought about this in a while but this post has reinvigorated me. I will see how this works, thank you!

Comment: another question is if the serial number would be different on different rpi's that were clones of one another...

Comment: @hunter For my understanding the serial number is on the hardware, burned into a read only chip. You may have a clone of the operating system but not of the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2):

[here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/how-do-i-get-the-serial-number) is a related question.

Briefly, you could read the file `/proc/cpuinfo` which would produce a listing like so

```
#cat /proc/cpuinfo

processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt                                                                                                                      vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor       : 1
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt                                                                                                                      vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor       : 2
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt                                                                                                                      vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor       : 3
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt                                                                                                                      vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

Hardware        : BCM2709
Revision        : a02082
Serial          : 000000003d1d1c36
```

The last line should give you what you need.

you could use a

- python script to read the serial number (as described in the link) and launch the chromium browser with the right argument using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) module (the linked question's answers have such examples)
- if you commandline savvy [`awk`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8720/33810) would give you a one liner

Comment: Does chromium offer any way to pull that variable and use it?

Comment: I doubt chromium would have such specialized functionality OOB. 
Moreover I'd think it would be a security problem the browser was able read arbitrary (system) files when requested by a page (via javascript).