# Unique Identifier for raspberry pi board

Tags: pi-2

Is there any unique identifier like the serial number (00000000xxxxxxxx), which is specific to an exact board? And which cannot be spoofed or cracked or changed? and can also be retrieved to identify the board type?

Thank you

Comment: Why won't the serial number work?

Comment: It is because, I read that it can easily be spoofed. I just wanted it to be unique

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to create a device using raspberry pi, which i should be able to continuously keep a track on. So I need that specific identifier to be unique and which cannot be spoofed or cracked or changed? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are your end users really like to change the serial number and what are the chances of that compared to just stealing it.

Comment: Have you considered a certificate based approach

Comment: Spoofed in what context? If you're going to transmit this unique id it can be changed or impersonated in the transmission. If so, you need a challenge-response approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only 2 identifiers which are more or less unqiue, I know about, are:

1. the **serial number** which you already mentioned, find more details about it [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/how-do-i-get-the-serial-number/)
2. the **MAC address** of the eth0 or wlan0 interface. for eth0 you could get it by using `cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address` or `ifconfig eth0 | grep HWaddr  | awk '{print $NF}'`. 
   The result will be something like `b8:27:eb:2e:6a:20`

The MAC address is only 48 bits and the serial number looks even less. So they are by no means cryptographically strong.

You could now generate a HMAC of these values, or maybe from both (by chaining).

You should consider that it is possible to disable the wlan0 interface (and probably the eth0 aswell). Which would void your MAC address result, so you need to test for that.

Comment: The MAC address is 24bit OUI, which is fixed for a specific vendor, and 24bit serial. Then, afaik, the MAC48 is generated from (lower bits?) of the Pi serial number.