# Output of cat command to a memory variable

Tags: bash

Newbie question, but I'm missing something

I'm issuing this command on my raspberry pi (zero 2W)
cat /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/serial-number

which works nicely.  Cat will output the command to stdout... but I want the output to a memory variable..

mcuSerialNumber=$( cat /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/serial-number )

Should, from what i read, put the output of cat to the memory variable.. but I get
[image]

if I (interactively) use this command
cat /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/serial-number
[image]

All i'm trying to do is read that file, and put the contents (red box) into a memory variable... argh .. newbie I know

Comment: There are plenty of (better) ways of accessing serial number https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/2086/8697

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a misunderstanding of the data type really, and you actually have the answer you probably wanted if you're willing to ignore the *warning*.

You can see this by sending your result to `stdout` using `echo` (remember, `cat` gave a **warning** - not an error):

```bash
$ mcuSerialNumber=$(cat /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/serial-number)
-bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
$ echo $mcuSerialNumber
00000000eccd2fff
```

Let me attempt an explanation: The data at `/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/serial-number` is a [*null-terminated string*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) - which `cat` is not designed to handle - at least not without a squawk.

You have two choices: ignore the squawk/warning, or read it using a different method; e.g.:

- using the little-known `strings` utility:

```bash
$ strings /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/serial-number
00000000eccd2fff
```

- or `tr`:

```bash
$tr < /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/serial-number -d '\0'
00000000eccd2fff
```

- or `sed`

```bash
$ sed 's/\0//' /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/serial-number
0000000eccd2fff
```

- or `awk`

```bash
$ awk -F /0 'NR == 1 { print $0 }' /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/serial-number
00000000eccd2fff
```

Alternatively, the same serial number is also available in the file `/proc/cpuinfo` file, but ***not*** a null-terminated string, so you can do something [like this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/116928/83790):

```bash
$ grep Serial /proc/cpuinfo
Serial      : 00000000eccd2fff
```

Comment: Not sure why they would consider a question on Raspberry PI scripting language an off-topic question.  As always, I wonder why moderators would close a question that was obviously helpful, as it was closed AFTER the answer was accepted.  Moderators may not find it helpful, but the users of the web site did!

Comment: @codeputer: I'm not sure either... the logic often escapes me. They frequently declare hardware-related questions off-topic, and now software-related questions. Oddly, network-related questions seems to be surviving. So yeah... I don't understand it.